# Order by key from a Map in a Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I want to order by timestamp some avro files that I retrieve from HDFS.

The schema of my avro files is :

> headers : Map[String,String], body : String

Now the tricky part is that the timestamp **is one of** the key/value from the map. So I have the timestamp contained in the map like this :

> key_1 -> value_1, key_2 -> value_2, timestamp -> 1234567, key_n ->
>   value_n

**Note that the type of the values is String.**

I created a case class to create my dataset with this schema :

```
case class Root(headers : Map[String,String], body: String)
```

Creation of my dataset :

```
val ds = spark
          .read
          .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
          .load(pathToHDFS)
          .as[Root]
```

I don't really know how to begin with this problem since I can only get the columns headers and body. How can I get the nested values to finally sort by timestamp ?

I would like to do something like this :

```
ds.select("headers").doSomethingToGetTheMapStructure.doSomeConversionStringToTimeStampForTheColumnTimeStamp("timestamp").orderBy("timestamp")
```

A little precision : I don't want to loose any data from my initial dataset, just a sorting operation.

I use Spark 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loaded `Dataset` should look something similar to the sample dataset below:

```
case class Root(headers : Map[String, String], body: String)

val ds = Seq(
  Root(Map("k11"->"v11", "timestamp"->"1554231600", "k12"->"v12"), "body1"),
  Root(Map("k21"->"v21", "timestamp"->"1554134400", "k22"->"v22"), "body2")
).toDS
```

You can simply look up the `Map` by the `timestamp` key, `cast` the value to `Long`, and perform an `orderBy` as follows:

```
ds.
  withColumn("ts", $"headers"("timestamp").cast("Long")).
  orderBy("ts").
  show(false)
// +-------------------------------------------------+-----+----------+
// |headers                                          |body |ts        |
// +-------------------------------------------------+-----+----------+
// |[k21 -> v21, timestamp -> 1554134400, k22 -> v22]|body2|1554134400|
// |[k11 -> v11, timestamp -> 1554231600, k12 -> v12]|body1|1554231600|
// +-------------------------------------------------+-----+----------+
```

Note that `$"headers"("timestamp")` is just the same as using the [`apply`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@apply(extraction:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) column method (i.e. `$"headers".apply("timestamp")`).

Alternatively, you could also use [`getItem`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@getItem(key:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to access the `Map` by key, like:

```
$"headers".getItem("timestamp")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. How did you manage to find this syntax to access the timestamp key ? Is there a documentation I'm missing ?

Comment: @Gatsby, please see my expanded answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Scala's sortBy, which takes a function. I would advise you to explicitly declare  the val ds as a Vector (or other collection), that way you will see the applicable functions in IntelliJ (if you're using IntelliJ) and it will definitely compile.

See my example below based on your code :

```
  case class Root(headers : Map[String,String], body: String)

  val ds: Vector[Root] = spark
    .read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .load(pathToHDFS)
    .as[Root]

  val sorted = ds.sortBy(r => r.headers.get("timestamp").map(PROCESSING) ).reverse
```

Edit: added reverse (assuming you want it descending). Inside the function  that you pass as argument, you would also put the processing to timestamp.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly thanks but in the case where I need spark distributed performances for a large dataset how can I proceed ?

Comment: In addition the type of ds is Dataset[Root], in order to get a Vector you need "to get rid of" spark dataset abstraction by doing a collect like this : val test : Vector[Root] = spark
      .read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
      .load("path")
      .as[Root]
      .collect
      .to[Vector]

Comment: Here is a git gist showing you your solution : https://gist.github.com/christopheblp/bb6f5de3e8cd910bff74e3aefdfef0fe

Comment: Thank you for sharing the gist. Glad to hear my solution works for you

Comment: " but in the case where I need spark distributed performances for a large dataset how can I proceed ? "  >>> To be honest I'm not very familiar with Spark. Checked out the DataSet api, which I see is optimized for Spark's distributed computing. So you wouldn't have that specific optimization in a "normal" Scala Seq. I would suggest you use a Vector, which is optimized for large volumes. See [https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html] &[https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/1ynujn/collections_larger_than_2147483647_elements/]

Comment: As you can see in the table if you follow the first link https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html, Vector's operations should not be slower on large volumes: It is said to have effectively constant time,on all operations. It has much higher performance and max capacity than a Seq

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, Encoder, Dataset}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, desc}
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Nested(key_1: String,key_2: String,timestamp: Timestamp,key_n: String)
case class Root(headers:Nested,body:String)

implicit val rootCodec: Encoder[Root] = Encoders.product[Root]

val avroDS:Dataset[Root] = spark.read
                                .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
                                .load(pathToHDFS)
                                .as[Root]

val sortedDF: DataFrame = avroDS.orderBy(desc(col("timestamp")))
```

This code snippet would directly cast your Avro data to `Dataset[Root]`. You wont have to rely on importing `sparksession.implicits` and would eliminate the step of casting your **timestamp** field to **TimestampType**. Internally, Spark's Timestamp datatype is implemented using `java.sql.Timestamp`.